# How to terminate a running loop in java?

Tags: java, exit, terminate

Program A:

```
    public void startThreadPool2(boolean flag) {
    while(flag) {
        Runnable run = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("running");
            }
        };
        service.execute(run);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Program B:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SentimentAnalyse sentimentAnalyse = SentimentAnalyse.getInstance();
    sentimentAnalyse.startThreadPool2(true);
}
```

Program C:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //how to stop the while loop
}
```

A while loop keep running and I don't know how to stop it in another program.

//update
Your ways maybe all works, I find my singleton don't work due to eclipse use different class loader in different program.

Comment: The `flag` is passed by-value so the loop will run forever or not at all.  In addition, `while (flag) { if (flag == false) break; ... }` is redundant.

Comment: It is not clear what loop you refer to in a Program C.

Comment: Stop while loop in A called by program B. I don't know how to explain these exactly. Maybe we can say stop program B or stop the while loop in program A.

Comment: The flag doesn't matter. You can think it is while(true).

Comment: Is this loop executed in the same thread as the `main` method of a program C or not?

Comment: I don't know that. @user2040251

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the flag in the SentimentAnalyse and provide a setter for it!
In porgram c (what ever this is) you need a reference to the instance of SentimentAnalyse, that you've created in program b. Stop the loop in programm a by calling its setter with false from program c

Comment: It seems don't work. I can find same instance by using Singleton. In program B, it have call startThreadPool2() with while(true). If I set the flag in C, that means calling startThreadPool2() with while(false), and nothing happen. We can find same instance, but we can't find the method.